# Room Database callback() dose not prepopulating the Database in first Install on creating the Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, callback, android-room

I am trying to fetch data as " Live Data List of AttendanceInfo" in my ViewModel
and when I try to log

```
Log.i("d", last30dayes.value?.get(0).toString())
```

It is giving me:`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

I assume it happens because my database is not populating initially while creating the database

but Why is that happening? where is the problem?
*/

it works fine until I reinstall the app in new AVD upgrading from android 10 to android 10+ and
also writing some more code

This is my **DataBase**:

```
abstract val employeInfoDAO: EmployeInfoDAO

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: EmployeInfoDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): EmployeInfoDatabase {
        synchronized(this) {
            var instance = INSTANCE
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext, EmployeInfoDatabase::class.java,
                    "employes_attendance_database"
                ).addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute{
                            instance?.employeInfoDAO?.insertDateList(DateDataGenerator.addDate())
                        }
                    }
                }).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
            }
            return instance
        }

    }
}
```

This is my **DateDataGenerator** class:

```
companion object {
    fun addDate(): List<AttendanceInfo>{
        val dt = LocalDate.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd,,E,,MMMM, yyyy")
        val l = mutableListOf<AttendanceInfo>()
        for (i in 30 downTo 0){
            val date = dt.minusDays(i.toLong()).format(formatter)
            l += AttendanceInfo(0, mutableListOf(), mutableMapOf(),date)
        }
        return l.toList()
    }

}
```

//This is my data class AttendanceInfo(

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val date_id: Long = 0L,

@ColumnInfo(name = "present_list")
@field:TypeConverters(ListConverter::class)
val presentEmploye: MutableList<Long>,

@ColumnInfo(name = "extra_map")
@field:TypeConverters(MapConverter::class)
val extra : MutableMap<Long,Int>,

val date_: String
```

Comment: Are you sure this is room exception? put the full trace please, it could be `recyclerView` exception, if you are using..

Comment: it can't be because i have used the recyclerView part before when i populate database in 1st run but when i reinstall it, it isn't working.. i don't know why.

Comment: post the full stack trace